# What is raw code of textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, button, textbox

May be i can get some negative points on this question but, really this question is boggling in my mind from last many days that what is the basic/raw code behind textbox(or other such controls).

i mean i understands that, we can inherit the textbox class and make our changes, we creates its object and use it.

but wants to know how that class creates a textbox(the design which allow us to enter text) (same query for other components), is it a code of 'C' language which are generating it using CG (computer graphics) programming or any other thing.

Experts please resolve my curiosity.

Thanks

Comment: You are asking about WinForms on Windows desktop, right? Because it will be different in WPF, different in Siverlight, and obviously different in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows provides several basic API's for drawing on the screen. You can draw pixels, lines, boxes and more complex geometric shapes. There are also API's to draw text. Other API's allow you to react to user input, e.g. mouse movement and clicks and keyboard input.

From these basic API's you can create your own text box by drawing the exact pixels of how the text box should look and react to user input. However, Windows has a built-in concept of a text box. This text box has a standard look and feel and is also integrated with UI concepts like focus, tab order, the clipboard and the caret. But behind the scenes Windows is using the low level API functions to draw on the screen and react to user input.

When you create a [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) in Windows Forms it actually creates and wraps a standard Windows [Edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775458%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This control is drawn using GDI. However, other programming models like WPF may create [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) controls that looks like a normal text box but uses a custom implementation supplied by WPF and is drawn using DirectX.

Answer (score 4):

Use http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ and see for yourself...

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I think it is doing:

The Raw code behind `TextBox` or any other `Control` uses `Windows API` that is responsible for drawing these controls and provide `Handles` of these controls for later reference.

Windows has been using different methods to draw it's UI like `GDI`, `GDI+` and sometimes `DirectX`. I may be wrong and there may be some other techs I forgot to mention.

These controls use each window's `WinProc` to receive `Input Notification` and other callbacks that notify these controls when clicked, typed or for example resized.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, got it, can you please give a good link for this.

Comment: Well, if you have not programmed Windows in C/C++, you won't be familiar with these things. Take a look at the following link : http://pravin.insanitybegins.com/win32/

Comment: thanks, i have done some programming with C and C++ but at normal level. so hopefully i would be able to understand. but thanks to open some of windows of my mind.